# A Python script with threads in a duplicated process on Linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I am running a Python script (version 3.6.8) on AWS t2.micro instance with Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03. The script runs two long-running threads as shown below.

I monitor CPU and memory usage with htop, which shows 2 processes for my script both taking resources. Based on the output it doesn't seem like two processes are actually running. On macOS, where I developed the script, htop shows only 1 process for my script.
The first image below shows collapsed processes on Linux and the second one shows them in a tree view.

Am I using Python threads the wrong way? Or do macOS and Linux show processes for python script differently?

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def thread(sec_sleep):
    while 1:
        print('sleep', sec_sleep)
        sleep(sec_sleep)


def init_services():
    t = Thread(target=thread, args=(1, ))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


def main():
    init_services()
    thread(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: output looks fine to me ... what do you mean when you say the output makes it look like they are not both running ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is nothing wrong with that. `htop` shows individual threads as separate processes by default. If you are press capital `H` it will show only main process(press again to switch back).